# Working with Bitmap? Giving error?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am using Bitmap for finding the width and hight of the image. When i write the code it is giving error: Parameter is not a valid.

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("./Images/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"].ToString()));
```

I am getting error can you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the full error message including Stack Trace and also debug and add the value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"]` - currently we don't have enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says that the *image* you are saving has invalid image data (state) or the filename which is used to save image is already is in used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to use this

```
System.Drawing.Image bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("YourPathHere"));
```